# GoogleTagManager | Parsing URL - With or Without regex

Tags: regex, url, google-tag-manager

I want to pass into a variable, the language of the user.
But, my client can't/didn't pass this information trough datalayer. So, the unique solution I've is to use the URL Path.

Indeed - The structure is:
http://www.website.be/en/subcategory/subsubcategory
I want to extract "en" information

No idea to get this - I check on Stack, on google, some people talk about regex, other ones about CustomJS, but, no result on my specific setup.

Do you have an idea how to proceed on this point ?

Many thanks !!
Ludo

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the built in {{Page Path}} variable is enabled. Create a custom Javascript variable.

```
function() {
   var parts = {{Page Path}}.split("/");
   return parts[1];
}
```

This splits the path by the path delimiter "/" and gives you an array with the parts. Since the page path has a leading slash (I think), the first part is empty, so you return the second one (since array indexing starts with 0 the second array element has the index 1).

This might need a bit of refinement (for pages that do not start with a language signifier, if any), but that's the basic idea.

Regex is an alternative (via the regex table variable), but the above solution is a little easier to implement.